# mvc4 Automatically log in user during email-confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I send out an Email with a confirmation tocken (from the webpages_Membership table) when the user registers on my site.

When the user clicks the link I confirm the Account:

```
 WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(guid);
```

I would now like to log the user in as sugested in this post: [Is it a bad idea to automatically log users in from an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586500/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-automatically-log-users-in-from-an-email)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the standard membership system, you should call

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx